# With Wordpress, how do I link to an image to use as a background in my style.css file?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I know in HTML/PHP files I can do something like

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/path/to/image.png" />
```

but in CSS, obviously I can't do this if I want to do

```
background: url('<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/linen.png');
```

even though I want to.

How would I go about achieving a similar effect?

Comment: tell your server to treat .css files as php scripts, and then you can embed php code in them. as long as the code outputs valid css, it'd be basically be invisible to the end user.

Comment: What about using google There are millions of examples for this.

Comment: You could just put that bit of the CSS in your template.

Comment: Just use something like this #header { background: url(images/header-bg.png);}

Comment: @arkascha: There are "millions of examples" for almost all the question asked here at google.

Comment: To expand on @NikosTsirakis answer, put your images in the theme folder and use a relative path. Image URLs in a style sheet are resolved relative to the style sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should't use `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>` in the CSS files.
URLs in CSS files are relative to the current CSS file.

So, if you have following directory structure

```
theme/
    images/
        linen.png
    css/
        styles.css
```

you CSS rule will look like

```
background: url('../images/linen.png');
```